# writing CVS files from application does not put it in proper format - causes issue

Tags: csv, vb6

So I have a table in SQLSERVEr from where I select data and try to write it to a .CSV file. Everything looks good, but for some reason the first column of data seems to be in some weird kind of format because, I am unable to align text to text or right. When I do click on one of the alignment button, the text in the column barely moves. All other data seems to be fine, I feel like the first column is the only problematic one.

Here's what my code looks like

```
Dim sSQL As String
Dim cRS As ADODB.Recordset
Dim T As Long
Dim b As Long
Dim strLine As Variant

sSQL = ""
sSQL = "X, Y, Z from tblA” 

Set cRS = New Recordset

cRS.Open sSQL, g_cn, adOpenStatic
If cRS.RecordCount > 0 Then
    cRS.MoveLast
    T = cRS.RecordCount
    cRS.MoveFirst
Else
    T = 0
End If

Open filenameCSV For Output As #1

For b = 1 To T
    strLine = ""
    strLine = cRS!X & ","
    strLine = strLine & cRS!Y & ","
    strLine = strLine & cRS!Z & ","

    Print #1, , strLine 
    cRS.MoveNext
Next

Close #1
cRS.Close
Set cRS = Nothing
```

So like I said, this code works. It writes data properly to .CSV except with the formatting in the first column, mainly column X

Instead of Print #1, I tried Put #1 but that gives me an error saying Bad File Code

This .csv file is being loaded into some finance software, and i believe the formatting in column X is causing the issues, basically the software does not recognize a value in that column.

FYI..I simpliefied the query.

Anyone have any ideas?

EDIT:

I tried running it from a new file

And I added VBCRLF at the end of the loop before I move to next recordset

```
strLine = strLine & vbCrLf
    Put #1, , strLine
```

The .csv file gets created but I get a weird symbol in each cell in teh first column

[image]
EDIT2 : Opened with Notepad++

[image]

Comment: Is it possible you have quotes, newlines or commas in your data, causing the CSV to be corrupted?

Comment: @CharlieDalsass well the file actually had data in it prior to opening, so i actually clear it here     Open filenameCSV For Output As #1. But this data comes directly from SQL SERVER as is show

Comment: @CharlieDalsass i'm not sure if the factc that i re-use a .csv file can cause this issue

Comment: You might try using a new file to eliminate that possiblity. Also, where is your CRLF (line feed) at end of each line?

Comment: @CharlieDalsass something like strline=strline & vbcrlf ? I'll try it now with a new file

Comment: @CharlieDalsass see my edit

Comment: @BobSki It could be that you are getting some sort of non-printable characters from whatever source data you are using.  Are you using any sort of CHR or ASC coding in building your string to output?  Can you open the CSV in something like Notepad++ which can show control characters and see what those boxes really are?

Comment: @LukeG. - so this is teh whole process. I create a .CSV file, then read teh file, instert into SQL SERVER, then I query it and write it again to .CSV. Check out Edit 2

Comment: Also, I'm not sure if I'm supposed to to Open File For Binary, or For Output as #1. As it is shown above it says For Output - I was able to do that with Print #1 . But Right now I have it as For BINARY AS #1 and Put #1

Comment: So i changed it to Open File for Output as #1 , then at the end of the loop I did Print #1, Strline (only one comma, previously I had two as can be seen above and it seems to create it correctly now)

Comment: @BobSki Yes, for plain-text you'll want to use open for output and print.  That is very strange that you were getting nulls and...backspaces?  I guess it was converting your text into some sort of binary mess.  But it is working properly now with your actual dataset?

Comment: @luke g yes its fine now i opened it with notepad++ and everything lools good